# Tying to solve a problem regarding displaying shipping costs where one package is costlier than the other (Java)

Tags: java

I'm currently working on an assignment which takes input values from the user length, height, width calculates the volume, with a helper method that the base price for a package with volume <=1 is $3, and for every unit increase in volume, the cost increase is $1.
The code will display the cost of shipping for the two packages and output the difference between the two shipping costs.

Where I am stuck is I believe where I was confusing myself was one of the requirements is

i. if there is no difference, display the costs are the same.

ii. If the cost of one is less than twice the other, display that it is “slightly more than

iii.”If the cost of one is less than three times the other, display that it is “twice”

iv. If the cost of one is less than four times the other, display that it is “triple”

v. If the cost of one is less than five times the other, display that it is “quadruple”

vi. otherwise, display that it is the calculated multiple

```
public class Shipment {
private Package pack1, pack2;
private String message;
private NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
public Shipment() {

    System.out.println("Welcome to Jaylen Carroll's shipping calculator!!");
    this.pack1 = new Package();
    this.pack2 = new Package();
    message = "";
}// prints the title uses default constructor and 

public void inputPackages() {
    System.out.println("Enter first package dimensions");
    inputPackage(this.pack1);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter second package dimensions");
    inputPackage(this.pack2);
}

public void inputPackage(Package pack) {
    pack.inputLength();
    pack.inputWidth();
    pack.inputHeight();
}

public void calculateCost() {
    double volP1 = pack1.calcVolume();
    double volP2 = pack2.calcVolume();
    double costPack1 = 3+(volP1-1);
    double costPack2 = 3+(volP2-1);

System.out.println("Package 1 will cost "+costPack1);
System.out.println("Package 2 will cost "+costPack2);

    if(volP1 == volP2) {
        System.out.println("The shipping costs are the same.");

/* How can I get this if statement to print the cost difference and display which one is more expensive than the other.*/

}

public void display() {
    System.out.print("First package dimensions: ");
    this.pack1.displayDimensions();
    //add memo about shipping
    
    System.out.print("Second package dimensions: ");
    this.pack2.displayDimensions();
    //add memo about shipping 
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by other if statement?

Comment: Agree, I do also not understand where the problem exactly is. Could you please improve the question, to what you want the program to do, and where it fails to do so?

Comment: I have updated my post, my bio was very unclear of what I wanted to do with the method. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you're looking?

```
if(volP1 == volP2) {
            System.out.println("The shipping costs are the same.");
        }else if(volP1 < (2*volP2)){
            double result = volP2 - volP1;
            System.out.println("Package one is " +result +" cheaper than package two");

        }
```